# free a struct of a linked list that have struct nodes

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, free

*I have a struct of a linked list the have a node struct inside*

```
struct gradeNode {
char courseName[sizeName];
int grade;
struct gradeNode *next;
struct gradeNode *prev;

struct gradeList {
struct gradeNode *head;
struct gradeNode *next;
```

I'm trying to destroy the list free!! but i get exception of access violation any help

```
void destroyList(struct gradeList *head)
{
    struct gradeNode* tmp;

    while (head!= NULL)
    {
        tmp = head;
        head = head->next;

        free(tmp);
    }

    free(head);
}
```

Here is the main

```
int i = 0;
for (i; i < numOfStuds; i++) {
    destroyList(&students[i].gradelist);
}
```

Comment: `students[i].gradelist` what is the type of it?

Comment: @coderredoc students is array struct the have list for every i the list is gradelist type

Comment: You are calling `free` twice on `head`, in while loop and after it.

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. Provide a complete example

Comment: The problem is that i cant access the next of head its says access violation

Comment: `tmp = head;` You're assigning your `struct gradeList *` to a variable of type `struct gradeNode *` and freeing that.

Comment: I rolled back the last edit because it changed the definition of `struct gradeNode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void destroyList(struct gradeList *head)
{
    struct gradeNode* tmp;

    while (head!= NULL)
    {
        tmp = head; //<<<<<<< assigning a struct gradeList* to a struct gradeNode*
        head = head->next;

        free(tmp); //<<<<<<< freeing the alias
    }
```

You're assigning a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type and then freeing it, which is especially problematic since `struct gradeList` appears to be a member of `struct gradeNode`.

Check your warnings. Are you not getting a warning for `tmp = head`? With gcc 7.2 I get:

> [x86-64 gcc 7.2 #1] warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

https://godbolt.org/g/EWfLCn